# MAMP access over local network

Tags: mamp-pro

I have MAMP Pro 4 running on a Macbook Pro, with virtual hosts. It's working fine. I want to be able to access it from other devices on my local network in order to test various browser / os combinations. All the articles and posts I have found online are for earlier versions, and or don't seem to work, or require additional software, ... I know this is easy -- I had it working a few years ago, but I don't recall how I did it. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply configure you projects host:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try: http:// ip-address-of-your-MAMP-installation:8080 
if it connects, fine is working.

Now the domain names. Because your are running locally and your test domains will not be resolved/routed, you need to change the "hosts" file.

Use the other Mac from where you want test.

Select "Go to Folder" and enter "/etc", there is a file called "hosts". Open it with  a text editor (Wrangler,TextMate...)

Then add a line at the end:

Save it (requires the admin password).

Now enter "http:// name of the domain:8080" and it should connect you to the MAMP domain.

A more elegant way is to install a local DNS server, but that's a complete different story.

Greetings,

Peter

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Let me give more detail.

On my Mac, http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin, for example, does the expected thing. However, the Mac's local net address is 10.0.1.2, and http://10.0.1.2:8888/phpMyAdmin gets a 403 (Forbidden).

Even if that did work, that would be matching MAMP's idea of localhost, not any particualr virtual host.

Comment: Hi, yes, because you didn't assign a folder. Assign a folder for "localhost", this should do it.

Comment: localhost does have and has had a folder (directory) assigned to it in MAMP's console. Same for the virtual host of interest. That's not it. Hmm... Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

External network access to phpmyadmin has to be allowed specifically.

[This is what I used a long time ago](https://squeezesetup.wordpress.com/allowing-network-access-to-phpmyadmin/).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the network name of your macbook.
You can set it in the system settings.
Let say that your macbook's network name is my-macbook
Then, to acess the served website / phpMyadmin, you can simply type `my-macbook.local:8888` (assuming that Mamp serves on the port `8888`).